# How to get key of second argument in in_array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (array01) that contains a bunch of sub arrays consisting of two pieces of data each, like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10CC [1] => Dreadlock Holiday )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 10CC [1] => I\'m Not In Love )
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 10CC [1] => Dreadlock Holiday ) )
         etc...
```

I have another array (array02) like:

```
Array ( [66] => Array ( [0] => 10CC [1] => Dreadlock Holiday )
        [585] => Array ( [0] => 10CC [1] => I\'m Not In Love )
         etc...
```

I'm successfully using foreach and then in_array to see what array01 elements are in array02.  However, what I am struggling to figure out is how to get the id of what element in array2 the hit was on.

So for example, array01's 0 and 2 elements (both 10CC, Dreadlock Holiday), are matched in array02, but how do I get the ID of the element (in this case, 66)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search) function?

Answer (score 0):

look for documentation for the array_intersect() in PHP manual. Note that the original keys are preserved so it returns an array with the elements present on the array02 array with the original keys.

Hope it's what you're looking for

Cheers